# Why this code is not giving result after making a query : Perfect 2.0 Swift?

Tags: swift, perfect

I am using Perfect 2.0 - swift to store values in my Database table which i created with XAMPP/phpmyadmin.

But after running query from swift code. the result from

```
mysql.storeResults()
```

is nill.

However, i can see that the data is getting stored and query has succeeded.

Following is my code :-

```
routes.add(method: .post, uri: "/signup") { (request, response) in

let requestParams = request.postParams
print(request.postParams)
let firstName = request.param(name: "firstName", defaultValue: "")
let lastName = request.param(name: "lastName", defaultValue: "")
let email = request.param(name: "email", defaultValue: "")
let password = request.param(name: "password", defaultValue: "")
let address = request.param(name: "address", defaultValue: "")
let city = request.param(name: "city", defaultValue: "")

var responseData = ""

guard !(firstName?.isEmpty)! else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: "firstName is required!")
    return
}

guard !(lastName?.isEmpty)! else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: "lastName is required!")
    return
}

guard !(email?.isEmpty)! else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: "email is required!")
    return
}

guard !(password?.isEmpty)! else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: "password is required!")
    return
}

guard !(address?.isEmpty)! else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: "address is required!")
    return
}

guard !(city?.isEmpty)! else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: "city is required!")
    return
}


let mysql = MySQL()

let connected = mysql.connect(host: dbHost, user: dbUser, password: dbPassword, db: dbName)

guard connected else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: mysql.errorMessage())
    return
}
defer {
    mysql.close()
    response.appendBody(string: responseData)
    response.completed()
}
var querySuccess = mysql.query(statement: "INSERT INTO Users (firstName,lastName,email,password,address,city) VALUES ('\(firstName!)', '\(lastName!)', '\(email!)', '\(password!)', '\(address!)', '\(city!)' )")

guard querySuccess else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: mysql.errorMessage())
    return
}

guard let results = mysql.storeResults() else {
    responseData = HelperMethods.createErrorResponse(status: 0, message: mysql.errorMessage())
    return
}

var array = [[String:Any]]()

results.forEachRow(callback: { row in
    let optionName = row[0]
    let optionValue = row[1]
    array.append([optionName!:optionValue])
})

responseData = HelperMethods.createSuccessResponse(status: 1, message: "success", data: array)
response.appendBody(string: responseData)
response.completed()


}
```

Comment: you should really use statements to prevent injection attacks. why are you setting an error response in your defer block? or at least why are you reusing an error named variable for non-error purposes? looks like you'll close & complete multiple times. i'm not convinced all MySQL features are implemented / available, such as storing the results and getting a response...

Comment: @Wain : this is my first time experience with any kind of server side programming language. so i don't know what features i am missing, i was just following the documentation available. but yes, you're right about the error named variable , i shouldn't have done that. BTW how do i use statements. i have read the documentation available, but it all went over my head.

Comment: statements are similar, basically you replace the parameters with `?` and supply an array, MySQL then inserts the parameters in a way that prevents any crap from damaging the DB